# Importing CSV files to database - Rejecting certain rows

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, csv

If I want to import a csv file, which would include an email column, is there a way
to only accept rows that have a valid email format and reject rows that have invalid formats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the rows while you digest them.
I normally parse the CSV and generate and save objects.
You could filter with standard validations.

If my controller has an `import` action and expects a `csv_file` parameter the controller action looks like:

```
def import
  require "csv"
  if params[:csv_file].present?
    CSV.parse(File.open(params[:csv_file].tempfile){|f| f.read}, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol) do |row|
      obj = MyObject.new(row)
      obj.save # validation filter rows
    end
  end
end
```

and in your model

```
validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex expression to match the column content before processing the row, e.g.:

```
CSV.foreach(path_to_file, :headers => true) do |row|
  if /\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+\z/.match(row['email'])
     #process the row (e.g. insert into database)
  end
end
```